# Partner ledger report empty even after creating invoice in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have imported customers table from another database and generated invoice in my current database for a particular customer.But when I tried to print the partner ledger it is empty.I have not modified source code
[image]
[image]

Comment: Check the destiny movement filter (put it to bring all) and take care of the fiscal year (even if you put a date filter delete the year), plus check if its a supplier/customer, bring both

Comment: I am creating new invoice for a customer,I have selected no filters option and fiscal year was set when I created the database few days ago.What might be the problem?

Comment: Im not sure, can you show me a picture of the partner ledger wizard and the asset of the invoice?

Comment: I uploaded invoice image and partner ledger report image.The report is empty for this customer and I am not able to find the reason

Comment: this is not a programming question -> Please ask on superuser.com.